# Вывод в столбик в qtextbrowser

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

На форме есть элемент `qTextBrowser`, в который добавляются элементы следующим образом:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STATE;i++) {
   ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(QString::number(m[i].nextstate[j]));
   ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(",");
   ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(QString::number(m[i].output[j]));
   ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText("      ");

   ui->textBrowser->append("");
}
```

Переход на следующую строку и имеет вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы столбцы выводились ровно? Что-то типа `std::setw`, только для `qTextBrowser`?

Comment: Ну, возможно, вас спасёт `"\t"` вместо пробелов. Если нет, то никак. Бейте на отдельные виджеты-колонки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте ваш шрифт моноширинным при помощи `SetFont()`.

После этого ваш `TextBrowser` ничем не будет отличаться от консоли - выведите ваш текст в `std::stringstream` при помощи привычного вам `setw`, а затем, получите из него строку методом `str()` и методом `QString::fromStdString()` перегоните ее в `QString`, который уже можно будет загнать в браузер.

Comment: А зачем смешивать `std::` и `Qt`? Есть `QTextStream::setFieldWidth`.

Comment: @alexolut есть два подхода к работе - использовать везде std и стыковаться с Qt только когда нужно обращение к GUI, или везде использовать Qt, как вы предлагаете. Стыковки с std есть практически у всех библиотек, а вот стыковки с Qt - нет.

Comment: Последнее предложение не совсем понял. Я сам не сторонник использовать `Qt`-обертки там, где можно использовать `std`. Но это в первую очередь касается простых функций, а не классов. Например, начиная с `Qt5`, разработчики наконец-то [осознали](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html), что не надо плодить лишних сущностей, а стоит использовать `std`. Но в текущем случае, я всё же за отсутствие смешивания `Qt` и `std`, именно по причине использования нетривиальных классов, а не простых алгоритмов.

Comment: @alexolut В моем последнем предложении я говорил о том, что при использовании нескольких библиотек возникают "трудности перевода", но практически всегда есть решение с промежуточным звеном в виде std.

Я предложил использовать std, так как автор уже знаком ним. В то же время, для знакомства с велосипедами Qt пришлось бы лезть в документацию.